# Парсинг сайта ДНС на Python не работает

Tags: python, парсер

https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a899cd16404e77/processory/p1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
r = requests.get('https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a899cd16404e77/processory/p1')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
for el in html.select(".container category-child > .products-page > .products-page__content > .products-page__list > .products-list > .products-list__content > .catalog-products view-simple > .catalog-product ui-button-widget"):
    title = el.select('.catalog-product__name ui-link ui-link_black > .span')
    if title:
        print(title)
    else:
        print('пусто')

#почему ничего не выводит?
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: потому что сайт не статичный, карточки товара подгружаются динамически и BS тут не помощник. Такие вещи парсятся вроде как с помощью Selenium