# Не работает парсинг PYTHON

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import os

url = 'https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/processory/?p=1'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
html = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

for c in html.find_all('div', class_="app-catalog-9gnskf e1259i3g0"):
    name = c.find('a')['title']

    print(name)
```

Что не так ? выдает <Response [200]> и всё

Comment: Сайт динамический, используйте selenium

Comment: Собственно, проблема точно такая же, как и в предыдущем вашем вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1566083/1365

Comment: @insolor, а есть хороший дубликат по поводу того, что вместо bs/requests/т.п. надо использовать selenium или подобное?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вот что-то такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/750096/1365

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, буду использовать для подобных вопросов. они тут частенько случаются.

Answer (score 0):

Сайт динамический. Поэтому библиотека requests не может его выполнить. Чтобы решить эту проблему,нужно использовать другую библиотеку, которая может имитировать поведение браузера и запускать JavaScript. Например, попробовать selenium.